# Using a rich text editor for category description?

Tags: categories

is it possible in Wordpress to have the category description use a rich text editor rather than a standard text area? If so any idea how to make it use one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two plugins that i know:

- [**Rich Category Editor**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-category-editor/)
- [**Category Description Editor**](http://www.laptoptips.ca/projects/category-description-editor/)

but I haven't tried them on the new 3.1 so check them out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried Rich Category Editor and it worked great. Not sure about on Wordpress 3.1 as the installation I'm using is only 2.8.5. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it

Comment: Do you know of a rich text editor for categories that is certified for WP 3.1? The category description editor works on 9 out of 10 WP 3.1 sites, but for some reason, I can't get it to work on some. (no plugins, 2010 theme)

Comment: @Scoot B: if it works on 3.1 9 out of 10 times then it should work on the 10th time also, it just doesn't make any scene. but like i said in the answer _"I haven't tried them on the new 3.1"_ so ireally can't tell whats the cause for that.

Comment: Neither of those work for me. WordPress 3.3.1